# Querying container with Linq + group by?

Tags: c#, linq, containers

I have this class:

```
public class ItemList
{
    public int GuID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public entityType Status { get; set; }
    public int Zone { get; set; }

    public class Waypoint
    {
        public int SubID { get; set; }
        public int Heading { get; set; }
        public float PosX { get; set; }
        public float PosY { get; set; }
        public float PosZ { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Waypoint> Routes = new List<Waypoint>();
}
```

Which is used on this List:
public List myList = new List();

New items are added to is like this:

```
ItemList newItem = new ItemList();
newItem.GUID = GUID;
newItem.ItemID = ItemID;
newItem.Name = Name;
newItem.Status = Status;

// Inner Routes List
ItemList.Waypoint itemLocation = new ItemList.Waypoint();
itemLocation.SubID = SubID;
itemLocation.Zone = Zone;
itemLocation.Heading = convertHeading(Heading);
itemLocation.PosX = PosX;
itemLocation.PosY = PosY;
itemLocation.PosZ = PosZ;
itemLocation.Rest = Rest;
newItem.Routes.Add(itemLocation);
myList.Add(newItem);
```

Now I need to group it by ItemID and join the first entry of Routes of each iqual ItemID.

This would be an example of `public List<ItemList> myList = new List<ItemList>();` data:

```
GUID    ItemID      ListOfRoutes
   1        20       GUID_1_Routes
   2        20       GUID_2_Routes
   3        20       GUID_3_Routes
   4        20       GUID_4_Routes
   5        20       GUID_5_Routes
   6        55       GUID_6_Routes
   7        55       GUID_7_Routes
   8        55       GUID_8_Routes
   9         1       GUID_9_Routes
  10         1      GUID_10_Routes
```

As you can see GUID is unique, ItemID can reapeat it self.
Each GUID has a Routes list and all routes list have a minimum of 1 entry and above.

Routes is part of the class ItemList `public List<Waypoint> Routes = new List<Waypoint>();`

**Routes example.**

GUID_1_Routes have:

```
Entry   Zone    SubID   Heading     PosX    PosY    PosZ
    1   1200        0       100     1029.32 837.21  29.10
    2   1200        0       120     1129.32 537.21  29.10
    3   1200        0       180     1229.32 137.21  29.10
    4   1200        0       360     1329.32 437.21  29.10
    5   1200        0       100     1429.32 637.21  29.10
```

GUID_2_Routes have:

```
Entry   Zone    SubID   Heading     PosX    PosY    PosZ
    1    100        0       10      129.32  437.21  29.10
```

So what I want to do is a list of all entries I have on myList grouped by ItemID maintainning the fields ItemID and Name ... and a new list per ItemID that will store the first element of each Routes from each GUID that had the same ItemID.

For example ItemID 20 would produce the follow result:

ItemID, Name, ListOfRoutes

This ItemID ListOfRoutes would contain

GUID_1_Routes first entry:

```
Entry   Zone    SubID   Heading     PosX    PosY    PosZ
    1   1200        0       100     1029.32 837.21  29.10
```

GUID_2_Routes first entry:

```
Entry   Zone    SubID   Heading     PosX    PosY    PosZ
    1    100        0       10      129.32  437.21  29.10
```

GUID_3_Routes, GUID_4_Routes, GUID_5_Routes first entries.

**UPDATE2:**

**This is how I have managed to get the results I wanted but I still belive it would be possible with a single query or in a better way then what I am currently using:**

```
        var query = from ItemList item in myList
                    where status.Contains(item.Status)
                    group item by new
                    {
                        item.ItemID,
                        item.Name,
                        item.Zone
                    }
                    into newList
                    orderby newList.Key.ItemID ascending
                    select new
                    {
                        newList.Key.ItemID,
                        newList.Key.Name,
                        newList.Key.Zone
                    };

        foreach (var thisItem in query)
        {
                var location = from n in myList
                               where n.ItemID == thisItem.ItemID
                               select new
                               {
                                   Routes = n.Routes.First()
                               };
                foreach (var thisObject in location)
                {
                    ItemList.Waypoint thisRoutes = thisObject.Routes;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're looking for is a variant of what I had in the first query.  I'm still not 100% sure I understood your explanation but based on your output, I believe this is more of what you were trying to do.

```
var query = from entry in myList
            where status.Contains(entry.Status)
            group entry.Routes.First() // take the first item in each route
                by new // assuming each id has a unique name
                {
                    entry.ItemID,
                    entry.Name
                }
                into g
            select new
            {
                g.Key.ItemID,
                g.Key.Name,
                ListOfRoutes = g.ToList() // return the grouping as list
            };
```

I wasn't sure about what type you wanted for the list, change it as necessary.

Comment: First of all happy new year and thanks for the answer I will try it, to explain more each item in the `public List<ItemList> myList = new List<ItemList>();` which has the class inside list of routes `public List<Waypoint> Routes = new List<Waypoint>();` but some items have more then 1 route and I need exactly the first entry of each item.

Comment: @Prim: Sounds to me like the first query is what you're looking for then.

Comment: @Jeff M unhappyly I am not being able to put the above to pratice into the current Class I have and the resultant query I also need the

Comment: @Prix: Ah oops, I just realized I got your name wrong.  Sorry.  :)  Could you provide a more complete example of some inputs and what you expect out?  Something in the form of the examples I've shown would be very helpful in describing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Jeff M thanks once again, I have updated the question hope the update is understandable.

Comment: @Jeff M once again thanks for the update, **At the end of the Question I have updated it with the working query** that I have been able to make but I still belive there is a better way to it and that it could fit into 1 query.

Answer (score 2):

- In your question, you say: "from each GUID that had the same ItemID."
- In your working code, you do not use GUID at all.

-

- In your question, you do not mention status filtering.
- In your working code, there is status filtering.

-

Anyway, I've boiled down the "working code" to a few lines.

```
from ItemList item in myList
where status.Contains(item.status)
group item by item.ItemID into groupedItems
order by groupedItems.Key descending
let firstItem = groupedItems.First()
let routes =
  from item2 in groupedItems
  select item2.Routes.First()
from route in routes
select new
{
  TheItemList = firstItem,
  TheWayPoint = route
};
```

You need to learn how to query the result of the group by operation.  In the above code, I have extracted the first element from each group, and I have projected each element of the group, then joined on that projection.

You should also communicate better what each key identifies, why there are duplicate item IDs in the list to begin with, and why a class named ItemList is not a List at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and happy new year to you ;), I will try your query in a few. About the GUID, it is because when I group it by ItemID there is no need to check for the GUID but you can see that each GUID has a Route list and from that route list i need the first element only. So if ItemID 20 has 5 GUID entries it meas i will have a Route list with 5 Elements which is the first element of each GUID that containned the ItemID